# Xcode debug C language get error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1)

Tags: c, xcode, debugging

Update @ 2014.05.01:

I create a new project with Xcode, and copy the bellow source code to the new project. Then the code runs as expected, and the error is gone.

So I suspect that it is the project configuration that cause the error. But both projects (the one with error and the one without error) use the Xcode default configuration. This **[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2Q5FIx_DSuvTG9rRTJuWDczUWs/edit?usp=sharing)** is the project with error, hope this will be helpful to find the problem.

====================

I am using Xcode to practice some small C language programs (project type: Command Line Tool, language: C).

But, I get a strange error when I am debugging my program. The source code is as follows:

```
//
//  main.c
//  c_review
//
//  Created by liudanking on 4/25/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 liudanking. All rights reserved.
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *base_add(const char *a, const char *b);
char *base_minus(const char *a, const char *b);
char *big_add(const char *a, const char *b);
char *big_minus(const char *a, const char *b);
char *big_multiply(const char *a, const char *b);
void align_big(const char *a, char *out);

void align_big(const char *a, char *out)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < strlen(a); i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != '0')
        {
            if (a[i] != '\0')
            {
                strcpy(out+99-strlen(a+i), a+i);
            }
            else
            {
                strcpy(out+98, "0");
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

char *base_add(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    char _a[100], _b[100];
    char *ret, *ret_align;
    int i, carry, sum_one;

    ret = (char*)malloc(101);
    if (ret == NULL)
    {
        printf("malloc failed");
    }
    memset(_a, '0', sizeof(_a));
    memset(_b, '0', sizeof(_b));
    memset(ret, '0', 101);
    ret[100] = '\0';

    // align a and b
    align_big(a, _a);
    align_big(b, _b);

    carry = 0;
    for (i=98; i>=0; i--)
    {

        sum_one = _a[i] - '0' + _b[i] - '0' + carry;
        carry = sum_one/10;
        sum_one = sum_one % 10;
        *(ret+i+1) = sum_one + '0';
    }

    for (i=0; i< 100; i++)
    {
        if (ret[i] != '0')
        {
            ret_align = (char*)malloc(120-i);
            if (ret[i] != '\0')
                strcpy(ret_align, ret+i);
            else
                strcpy(ret_align, "0");
            free(ret);
            break;
        }
    }

    return ret_align;
}

char *base_minus(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    char _a[100], _b[100];
    char *ret, *ret_align;
    int i, borrow, tmp;

    memset(_a, '0', sizeof(_a));
    memset(_b, '0', sizeof(_b));
    ret = (char*)malloc(100);
    memset(ret, '0', 100);
    ret[99] = '\0';

    // align a and b
    //strcpy(_a+(99-strlen(a)), a);
    //strcpy(_b+(99-strlen(b)), b);
    align_big(a, _a);
    align_big(b, _b);

    borrow = 0;
    for (i=98; i>=0; i--)
    {
        tmp = _a[i] - _b[i] - borrow;
        if (tmp >= 0)
        {
            ret[i] = tmp + '0';
            borrow = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            ret[i] = tmp + 10 + '0';
            borrow = 1;
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i< 100; i++)
    {
        if (ret[i] != '0')
        {
            ret_align = (char*)malloc(100-i);
            if (ret[i] != '\0')
                strcpy(ret_align, ret+i);
            else
                strcpy(ret_align, "0");
            free(ret);
            break;
        }
    }

    return ret_align;

}


char *big_add(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    char *ret, *p, *tp;
    char _a[100], _b[100];

    memset(_a, '0', sizeof(_a));
    memset(_b, '0', sizeof(_b));


    if (a[0] != '-' && b[0] != '-')
    {
        //        printf("%s+%s\n", a,b);
        return base_add(a, b);
    }
    printf("%d:%d:%d\n", a[0]!='-', b[0]=='-', a[0]!='-' && b[0]=='-');
    if (a[0]!='-' && b[0]=='-')
    {
        // align a and b
        printf("%d\n", strlen(a));
        strcpy(_a+99-strlen(a), a);
        strcpy(_b+(99-strlen(b)+1), b+1);
        if (strcmp(_a, _b) >= 0)
        {
            return base_minus(_a, _b);
        }
        else
        {
            p = base_minus(_b, _a);
            ret = (char*)malloc(102);
            ret[0] = '-';
            strcpy(ret+1, p);
            free(p);
            return ret;
        }
    }
    if (a[0] == '-' && b[0] != '-')
    {
        // align a and b
        strcpy(_a+(99-strlen(a)+1), a+1);
        strcpy(_b+(99-strlen(b)), b);
        if (strcmp(_a, _b) > 0)
        {
            p = base_minus(_a, _b);
            ret = (char*)malloc(102);
            ret[0] = '-';
            strcpy(ret+1, p);
            free(p);
            return ret;
        }
        else
        {
            return base_minus(_b, _a);
        }

    }
    if (a[0] == '-' && b[0] == '-')
    {
        p = base_add(a+1, b+1);
        ret = (char*)malloc(102);
        ret[0] = '-';
        strcpy(ret+1, p);
        free(p);
        return ret;
    }

    // return result
    return ret;
}

char *big_minus(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    char _b[100];

    memset(_b, '0', sizeof(_b));

    if (b[0] == '-')
    {
        return big_add(a, b+1);
    }
    else
    {
        _b[0] = '-';
        strcpy(_b+1, b);
        return big_add(a, _b);
    }

    return NULL;
}

char *big_multiply(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    char *ret, *p, *mid_ret;
    char _a[100], _b[100];
    int i, j, carry, sign, tmp;


    ret = (char*)malloc(202);
    p = (char*)malloc(202);
    memset(_a, '0', sizeof(_a));
    memset(_b, '0', sizeof(_b));
    memset(ret, '0', 202);
    ret[201]='\0';

    sign = 0;
    if (a[0] == '-')
    {
        sign++;
        strcpy(_a+99-strlen(a)+1, a+1);
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(_a+99-strlen(a), a);
    }
    if (b[0] == '-')
    {
        sign++;
        strcpy(_b+99-strlen(b)+1, b+1);
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(_b+99-strlen(b), b);
    }

    carry = 0;
    for (i=98; i>=0; i--)
    {
        memset(p, '0', 202);
        p[201]='\0';
        for (j=98; j>=0; j--)
        {
            tmp = (_b[i] - '0') * (_a[j] - '0') + carry;
            carry = tmp / 10;
            *(p+200+i-98 + j - 98) = tmp % 10 + '0';
        }
        mid_ret = big_add(ret, p);
        strcpy(ret, mid_ret);
        free(mid_ret);
    }

    free(p);
    return ret;
}



int main(void)
{
    char *ret, *ret2;
    char a[100], b[100], c[100], d[100];


    strcpy(a, "99");
    strcpy(b, "1001");

    //printf("%d, %s, %02x; %d, %s, %02x\n", sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]),a, a, sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]),b,b);

    ret = big_add(a, b);
    printf("%s\n", ret);
    if (ret)
        free(ret);

    strcpy(c, "99");
    strcpy(d, "1001");
    ret2 = big_minus(c, d);
    printf("%s\n", ret2);
    if (ret2)
        free(ret2);

    ret = big_multiply(a, b);
    printf("%s\n", ret);
    if (ret)
        free(ret);
    return 0;
}
```

Directly running the code in Xcode would get an error at line 93 "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x31)":

```
memset(_a, '0', sizeof(_a)); // Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x31)
```

But, if I run the compiled application in my terminal, with command **./my_app**, there is no error.

I checked the line carefully, but no bug was found.

When I move function implementations to the position that is after the main function (as bellow), the error is gone.

```
//
//  main.c
//  c_review
//
//  Created by liudanking on 4/25/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 liudanking. All rights reserved.
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *base_add(const char *a, const char *b);
char *base_minus(const char *a, const char *b);
char *big_add(const char *a, const char *b);
char *big_minus(const char *a, const char *b);
char *big_multiply(const char *a, const char *b);
void align_big(const char *a, char *out);




int main(void)
{
    char *ret, *ret2;
    char a[100], b[100], c[100], d[100];


    strcpy(a, "99");
    strcpy(b, "1001");

    //printf("%d, %s, %02x; %d, %s, %02x\n", sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]),a, a, sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]),b,b);

    ret = big_add(a, b);
    printf("%s\n", ret);
    if (ret)
        free(ret);

    strcpy(c, "99");
    strcpy(d, "1001");
    ret2 = big_minus(c, d);
    printf("%s\n", ret2);
    if (ret2)
        free(ret2);

    ret = big_multiply(a, b);
    printf("%s\n", ret);
    if (ret)
        free(ret);
    return 0;
}

void align_big(const char *a, char *out)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < strlen(a); i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != '0')
        {
            if (a[i] != '\0')
            {
                strcpy(out+99-strlen(a+i), a+i);
            }
            else
            {
                strcpy(out+98, "0");
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

char *base_add(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    char _a[100], _b[100];
    char *ret, *ret_align;
    int i, carry, sum_one;

    ret = (char*)malloc(101);
    if (ret == NULL)
    {
        printf("malloc failed");
    }
    memset(_a, '0', sizeof(_a));
    memset(_b, '0', sizeof(_b));
    memset(ret, '0', 101);
    ret[100] = '\0';

    // align a and b
    align_big(a, _a);
    align_big(b, _b);

    carry = 0;
    for (i=98; i>=0; i--)
    {

        sum_one = _a[i] - '0' + _b[i] - '0' + carry;
        carry = sum_one/10;
        sum_one = sum_one % 10;
        *(ret+i+1) = sum_one + '0';
    }

    for (i=0; i< 100; i++)
    {
        if (ret[i] != '0')
        {
            ret_align = (char*)malloc(120-i);
            if (ret[i] != '\0')
                strcpy(ret_align, ret+i);
            else
                strcpy(ret_align, "0");
            free(ret);
            break;
        }
    }

    return ret_align;
}

char *base_minus(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    char _a[100], _b[100];
    char *ret, *ret_align;
    int i, borrow, tmp;

    memset(_a, '0', sizeof(_a));
    memset(_b, '0', sizeof(_b));
    ret = (char*)malloc(100);
    memset(ret, '0', 100);
    ret[99] = '\0';

    // align a and b
    //strcpy(_a+(99-strlen(a)), a);
    //strcpy(_b+(99-strlen(b)), b);
    align_big(a, _a);
    align_big(b, _b);

    borrow = 0;
    for (i=98; i>=0; i--)
    {
        tmp = _a[i] - _b[i] - borrow;
        if (tmp >= 0)
        {
            ret[i] = tmp + '0';
            borrow = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            ret[i] = tmp + 10 + '0';
            borrow = 1;
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i< 100; i++)
    {
        if (ret[i] != '0')
        {
            ret_align = (char*)malloc(100-i);
            if (ret[i] != '\0')
                strcpy(ret_align, ret+i);
            else
                strcpy(ret_align, "0");
            free(ret);
            break;
        }
    }

    return ret_align;

}


char *big_add(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    char *ret, *p, *tp;
    char _a[100], _b[100];

    memset(_a, '0', sizeof(_a));
    memset(_b, '0', sizeof(_b));


    if (a[0] != '-' && b[0] != '-')
    {
        //        printf("%s+%s\n", a,b);
        return base_add(a, b);
    }
    printf("%d:%d:%d\n", a[0]!='-', b[0]=='-', a[0]!='-' && b[0]=='-');
    if (a[0]!='-' && b[0]=='-')
    {
        // align a and b
        printf("%d\n", strlen(a));
        strcpy(_a+99-strlen(a), a);
        strcpy(_b+(99-strlen(b)+1), b+1);
        if (strcmp(_a, _b) >= 0)
        {
            return base_minus(_a, _b);
        }
        else
        {
            p = base_minus(_b, _a);
            ret = (char*)malloc(102);
            ret[0] = '-';
            strcpy(ret+1, p);
            free(p);
            return ret;
        }
    }
    if (a[0] == '-' && b[0] != '-')
    {
        // align a and b
        strcpy(_a+(99-strlen(a)+1), a+1);
        strcpy(_b+(99-strlen(b)), b);
        if (strcmp(_a, _b) > 0)
        {
            p = base_minus(_a, _b);
            ret = (char*)malloc(102);
            ret[0] = '-';
            strcpy(ret+1, p);
            free(p);
            return ret;
        }
        else
        {
            return base_minus(_b, _a);
        }

    }
    if (a[0] == '-' && b[0] == '-')
    {
        p = base_add(a+1, b+1);
        ret = (char*)malloc(102);
        ret[0] = '-';
        strcpy(ret+1, p);
        free(p);
        return ret;
    }

    // return result
    return ret;
}

char *big_minus(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    char _b[100];

    memset(_b, '0', sizeof(_b));

    if (b[0] == '-')
    {
        return big_add(a, b+1);
    }
    else
    {
        _b[0] = '-';
        strcpy(_b+1, b);
        return big_add(a, _b);
    }

    return NULL;
}

char *big_multiply(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    char *ret, *p, *mid_ret;
    char _a[100], _b[100];
    int i, j, carry, sign, tmp;


    ret = (char*)malloc(202);
    p = (char*)malloc(202);
    memset(_a, '0', sizeof(_a));
    memset(_b, '0', sizeof(_b));
    memset(ret, '0', 202);
    ret[201]='\0';

    sign = 0;
    if (a[0] == '-')
    {
        sign++;
        strcpy(_a+99-strlen(a)+1, a+1);
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(_a+99-strlen(a), a);
    }
    if (b[0] == '-')
    {
        sign++;
        strcpy(_b+99-strlen(b)+1, b+1);
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(_b+99-strlen(b), b);
    }

    carry = 0;
    for (i=98; i>=0; i--)
    {
        memset(p, '0', 202);
        p[201]='\0';
        for (j=98; j>=0; j--)
        {
            tmp = (_b[i] - '0') * (_a[j] - '0') + carry;
            carry = tmp / 10;
            *(p+200+i-98 + j - 98) = tmp % 10 + '0';
        }
        mid_ret = big_add(ret, p);
        strcpy(ret, mid_ret);
        free(mid_ret);
    }

    free(p);
    return ret;
}
```

It is really strange...

What is wrong with my code? Anyone know the reason? :)

Comment: I get no errors with running that code either directly or within `lldb`...

Comment: After I update my Xcode to 5.1.1, the old problem is gone.

But a new problem as above incurs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the error you reported (when I build with Xcode 5.1.1).  But you asked "what is wrong with my code?", which is pretty open-ended.

Your symptoms are consistent with a corrupted stack.  Look for places where you might overwrite your character arrays.  Bad handling of zero-terminated strings is a rich source of bugs.  So are malloc and free if they are done wrong.

Let's just consider your function base_add.  I don't know if it "works" or not, but there are several things that look suspicious:

- Pointer "ret" comes from a malloc (line 46). If the malloc fails, you print an error message but then go ahead and use the invalid pointer anyway.
- Pointer "ret_align" comes from a malloc in an "if" block.  If the condition isn't true, the malloc never happens and ret_align isn't initialized.  But the function returns ret_align anyway.  This could easily make the caller crash.  Also, if the condition isn't true you don't free ret.  (The function crashes if you try to add "0" and "0".)

I could go on, but that should give you some places to start fixing the code.

You also have a couple of build warnings in function big_add.  Neither looks like it could cause your symptom, but you should fix them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and advice. But I still get the error when I run the code in my Xcode with Command+R. My OS is OSX 10.9.2. Could the OS be the problem?

Comment: I create a new project with Xcode, and copy the bellow source code to the new project. Then the code runs as expected, and the error is gone.

So I suspect that it is the project configuration that cause the error. But both projects (the one with error and the one without error) use the Xcode default configuration. This **[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2Q5FIx_DSuvTG9rRTJuWDczUWs/edit?usp=sharing)** is the project with error, hope this will be helpful to find the problem.

Comment: So far, I see no reason to blame either the OS version or the project configuration.  The symptoms come and go for no obvious reason; that suggests you are using uninitialized variables and/or pointers-to-random-places. I saw enough bugs in your code that I stopped looking for more. I suggest 2 strategies. 1st, go back to the project that shows the symptom and debug it until you understand why it fails. 2nd, study your source code and look for examples of the problems I've described. Hint: your original error said "(code=1, address=0x31)". 0x31 is NOT reasonable. How did _a get that address?